# How to Use Formula in SQL Query Dynamic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need your help to create query dynamically, 
how to populate data value from formula in other table.

Sample Below

```
Table A 
ID   Amount 
1    50 
2    40 
3    50 

Table B 
ID   FormulaID   VALUE 
X    1+2+3 
Y    1-2+3 

Result Expectation 
ID   FormulaID   VALUE 
X    1+2+3       140 
Y    1-2+3       60
```

Thanks

Comment: What front end are you using since it might be easier in the front end? Is the number of records in `Table A` fixed or less than 10 at least? Are the number of operations limited to + and - ? Is using Stored Procedures an option for you?

Comment: Hi Nai, Thanks for your response. ya it might be easier in the front end, but i will process this in the store procedure :). the number of records in table A is not fixed, it can be more than 10, and the operation is not only + and -, it can be like this (1*2)-(3+1).

Comment: There appears to be no direct way to do this, but since you're okay for SP, Break down the problem:.....first `select FormulaId from [Table B]` then loop through the records and get the numbers out by using `substring` while searching for `(+,-,*,/,(,)) into an `array`. For each element of the array 'select Amount from [Table A] where Id = ...`. Once you get a string with the actual values in it, use `exec` to essentially run the formula.

Comment: Once you have the replaced string, you can use `sp_executesql N'select 50+40+50'` (for example) to run the formula

Comment: i don't know,why this question is upvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

I Tired this based on @Ashwin Nair's comment..it works fine..

```
DECLARE @count INT = 1
DECLARE @Formula VARCHAR(200)
,@FormulaID VARCHAR(100)
,@IDstring VARCHAR(20)
,@operator VARCHAR(1)

CREATE TABLE #temp (RowID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),FormulaID VARCHAR(100),ID INT,SignOper VARCHAR(1),FORMULA VARCHAR(100),Flag INT,VALUE INT)
WHILE ( SELECT COUNT(*)FROM formulaT) >= @count
BEGIN
--Total formula records
SET @Formula = (SELECT formulaID FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RowID,*FROM formulaT) a WHERE RowID = @count)
SET @FormulaID = (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RowID,* FROM formulaT) a WHERE RowID = @count)
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Formula)
BEGIN
    WHILE @ID > 0
    BEGIN
        --spliting a formula --ID based on the charactors
        SET @IDstring = SUBSTRING(@Formula, 1, @ID - 1)
        SET @operator = SUBSTRING(@Formula, @ID, 1)
        SET @Formula = REPLACE(@Formula, @IDstring + @operator, '')
        INSERT INTO #temp
        SELECT @FormulaID,CAST(@IDstring AS INT),@operator,(SELECT CAST(Amount AS VARCHAR)  FROM amtt
                WHERE Id = CAST(@IDstring AS INT)),0,0
        SET @ID = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Formula)
        SET @IDstring = NULL
    END
    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT @FormulaID
        ,@Formula
        ,''
        ,(SELECT CAST(Amount AS VARCHAR)
            FROM amtt
            WHERE Id = CAST(@Formula AS INT))
        ,0,0
        --spliting a formula --ID based on the charactors
END
DECLARE @RowNo INT = (SELECT MIN(RowID) FROM #temp  WHERE FormulaID = @FormulaID)
SET @formula = ''
WHILE (SELECT MAX(RowID)FROM #temp WHERE FormulaID = @FormulaID) >= @RowNo
BEGIN
    SET @formula = @formula + (SELECT ISNULL(FORMULA + SignOper, SignOper)  FROM #temp  WHERE FormulaID = @FormulaID AND RowID = @RowNo)
    SET @RowNo = @RowNo + 1
END
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT @FormulaID
    ,0,'',@formula,1,0
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(250) = (SELECT 'sp_executesql N' + '''select ' + @formula + '''')
CREATE TABLE #CALC (VAL INT)
PRINT @QUERY
INSERT INTO #CALC
EXEC (@QUERY)
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT @FormulaID
    ,0,'',@formula,2,(SELECT val FROM #CALC ) 
DROP TABLE #CALC
SET @Count = @count + 1
END

SELECT F.ID
,F.FORMULAID
,FORMULA
,VALUE
FROM formulaT F
INNER JOIN #temp T ON T.FORMULAID = F.ID
AND T.FLAG = 2

DROP TABLE #temp
--Output
--ID  FORMULAID  FORMULA      VALUE
--X   1+2+3      50+40+50     140
--Y   1-2+3      50-40+50     60
--Please let me know this answer is helpful or not..
```

Thanks 
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

I think,your DB design is wrong.what is your real requirement like that lead you think about above DB design.you should throw little more background,you would get very professional solution in this community.

I have tried something ,just test with other sample data and give feedback.

```
DECLARE @TableB table(ID VARCHAR(50),FormulaID VARCHAR(50) ,VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES('X','1+2+3',NULL),('Y','1-2+3',NULL)

DECLARE @TableA table (ID INT,Amount INT)
INSERT INTO @TableA values(1,50 ),(2,40 ),(3,50 )

declare @input varchar(50)='a+b-c*d'
declare @delimiter varchar(50)='-+/*'


;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', FormulaID) > 0
                THEN substring(FormulaID, 0, PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', FormulaID))
            END numbers
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', FormulaID) > 0
                THEN substring(FormulaID, PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', FormulaID), 1)
            END delimeter
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', FormulaID) > 0
                THEN stuff(FormulaID, 1, PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', FormulaID), '')
            END input
        ,1 RN
        ,FormulaID
    FROM @TableB

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', input) > 0
                THEN cast(substring(input, 0, PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', input)) AS VARCHAR(50))
            ELSE cast(input AS VARCHAR(50))
            END
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', input) > 0
                THEN substring(input, PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', input), 1)
            END
        ,CASE 
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', input) > 0
                THEN stuff(input, 1, PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%', input), '')
            END
        ,RN + 1
        ,FormulaID
    FROM cte
    WHERE len(input) > 0
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT c.id
        ,c.numbers
        ,a.amount
        ,c.delimeter
        ,rn
        ,FormulaID
    FROM CTE C
    INNER JOIN @tableA a ON c.numbers = a.id
    )
    ,CTE4
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,formulaid
        ,amount
        ,delimeter
        ,numbers
        ,rn
    FROM cte1
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.id
        ,b.formulaid
        ,CASE 
            WHEN b.delimeter = '+'
                THEN b.amount + a.amount
            WHEN b.delimeter = '-'
                THEN b.amount - a.amount
            WHEN b.delimeter = '*'
                THEN b.amount * a.amount
            END
        ,a.delimeter
        ,a.numbers
        ,a.RN
    FROM cte1 a
    INNER JOIN cte4 b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.rn = b.rn + 1
    )
SELECT id
    ,formulaid
    ,amount
FROM cte4
WHERE delimeter IS NULL
```